# Wiremock JSON is proxying all the request also the saved ones

Tags: json, mapping, wiremock

In my below code, the thing is if i am trying to get responses for any of the request its getting proxied

```
{
    "mappings": [
        {
            "priority": 1,
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "urlPathPattern": "/container/epsSelfService/customers/([a-zA-Z1-9]*)/cashDepositTotals/([a-zA-Z1-9]*)"
            },
            "response": {
                "status": 200,
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                "bodyFileName": "depositlimitpersonalresponse.json"
            }
        },
        {
            "priority": 2,
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "urlPathPattern": "/container/epsSelfService/chubStartV1"
            },
            "response": {
                "status": 200,
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                "bodyFileName": "startclearinghub.json"
            }
        },
        {
            "priority": 3,
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "urlPathPattern": "/container/epsSelfService/chubSubmitV1"
            },
            "response": {
                "status": 200,
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                "bodyFileName": "submitclearinghub.json"
            }
        },
        {
            "priority": 4,
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "urlPathPattern": "/container/epsSelfService/chubValidateV1"
            },
            "response": {
                "status": 200,
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                "bodyFileName": "validateclearinghub.json"
            }
        },
        {
            "priority": 5,
            "request": {
                "method": "GET",
                "urlPathPattern": "/container/epsSelfService/chubCompleteV1"
            },
            "response": {
                "status": 200,
                "headers": {
                    "Content-Type": "application/json"
                },
                "bodyFileName": "completeclearinghub.json"
            }
        },
        {
            "priority": 100,
            "request": {
                "urlPathPattern": ".*"
            },
            "response": {
                "proxyBaseUrl": "http://localhost:922"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

tried to play around with the priority but no luck

Comment: What does one of your requests look like? If you remove your catch-all, priority 100 mapping, do you get a response? My initial thought is that your request matching for the other mappings is not correct, so everything falls through to the priority 100 mapping.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My Request is : curl http://localhost:80/container/epsSelfService/chubStartV1?deviceId=UA0080EB just a case that it has query parameter in addition to the actual request. not sure if the query parameter is not allowing it to match the request? @agoff

Comment: Using your mapping file, I'm able to get the `startclearinghub.json` response from the request you provided. What version of WireMock are you running?